# Diagonal Bracing Requirements

Tags: code-compliance, deck

I'm currently designing a deck to replace an existing deck on my home. The new deck is subject to different codes than when the original was built. The city provides a [link to a design guide](http://www.awc.org/pdf/codes-standards/publications/dca/AWC-DCA62009-DeckGuide-1007.pdf) which I am trying to follow.

[image: Diagonal Bracing Requirements diagram from design guide (p. 18/37)]

The deck will be 8' 8" (~2.64m) above grade and will require diagonal bracing. The image on the design guide is unclear as to where the bracing perpendicular to beam should connect to the blocking between joists. In the diagram, the joists are coincidentally the same width as the diagonal cut in the bracing. My joists will be 2x8. **Should the bracing connect to the top, middle, or bottom of the joist blocking?**

Some sections of the design guide reference IRC specifics, but this section does not. If someone could reference the specific IRC or applicable passage that would be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocking needs to be nailed in place through the decking as well as on the ends, so when the diagonal is connected to the top of the blocking, it will be connected to the strongest point of the blocking.

Comment: That would be my assumption, but measuring the 2' span from the bottom of the joists has me second guessing. Is the intent to create a 45° angle with 2' legs?

Comment: Yes the intent is to create a 45 degree angle. More importantly, a brace with no less than a 2 ft length. It can be longer. Code is always citing minimum requirements. It can be longer.